# Wordpress image uploading syntax error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am facing issue with Wordpress image uploading the error:
`syntaxerror: unexpected token b in json at position 0`

I have checked with the permissions which is fine.
Also, phpmyadmin the upload path looks perfect.

*** I crosschecked on the demosite there the image in getting uploaded on the server but, on frontend it looks broken.

Please help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Any errors in the browser console pointing to more specifics?

Comment: I don't have good knowledge with codes.

Comment: Take a look at how to check the console for errors https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Hi Andrew, I checked the console and the upload path which is showing there is invalid / wrong. It occurred due to a security plugin where I change the upload file name. Where can I change the path(file) of media uploads for new uploads and also, the previous uploads. Thanks.

Comment: Edit the wp-config.php file and set a new upload path define(‘UPLOADS’, ‘wp-content/myimages’);

Comment: The config file currently:- define('WP_TEMP_DIR',dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-content/uploads'); But, still is gives error.